# Выбрать первый элемент после текущего на том же уровне

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется следующая разметка:

```
<div class = "a">А не это</div>
<div class = "b">Жмем сюда</div>
<div class = "a">Получаем это</div>
```

При нажатии на `.b` нужно получить элемент на том же уровне, стоящий после него. Есть какая-то быстрая возможность это сделать или оптимальнее было бы окружить такие парные элементы div'ом?

Такой код, разумеется, возвращает элемент выше нажатого:

```
jQuery('.b').on('click', function() {
    alert(jQuery(this).siblings('.a').filter(':first').html());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можем лучше использовать [jQuery.next](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
jQuery(this).next('.a').html()
```

вместо

```
jQuery(this).siblings('.a').filter(':first').html()
```

см https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/q5xh0609/